# Spring Oauth2 client credentials flow example

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, microservices

I am trying to implement service to service security into spring boot services using spring oauth2. I want a service to access a secured resource of another service without any user action involved.

There are a lot of examples for authorization code grant type, but not very much about the client credentials grant type, which seems to be the right one for this use case.

I can set up the auth server and use a curl request to get a token.
The tests I found used Http Objects to check status codes.

How can I use the client credentials grant type in a java client with RestTemplate and spring oauth2?

I would think it must be as simple as adding a dependency, an annotation and a config file, yet I can't make it run.

Comment: Please update your question to add the code you tried and the errors you get. To improve your question please read How to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

And never ask for tutorial/working example as we are not here to teach/do your work for you

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple:

1. Create a `Config` class which is annotated with `@Configuration`.
2. In this class, create an instance implementing the interface `OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails`  and create a `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails` instance in that method. Add your values to it and return it.
3. Create a second instance of type `OAuth2RestTemplate` in the `Configuration` class and create in that method a `DefaultOAuth2ClientContext` instance by calling the default constructor. Then create an `OAuth2RestTemplate` and add the `OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails` instance and the `DefaultOAuth2ClientContext` instance to it. Subsequently return the `OAuth2RestTemplate` instance.
4. Add it with `@Autowired` in both your `Controller` and `Service` instances to use it.